# Replace a non-specific substring in a string

Tags: java, string, replace, substring, indexof

Well I'm trying to descover how to replace in a string like this:
`String user ="123124.Ken:000";` the substring `.Ken:000` with for example
`.Diana:999`. I think that there is something in using `indexOf()` of that `'.'` character but I don't know how to replace from that `indexOf()` to the end of `user` string.

Comment: You should parse the string into a domain class `User`, then change the properties you need to change, and finally serialize your domain object into the string again.

Comment: What about the `replace` or `replaceAll` methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
id = user.split(".")[0] # this will have the value of 123124
new user = id + ".Diana:999"
```

U can write a simple function like this.

```
def changeUser (oldUser, user):
    return oldUser.split('.')[0] + user
```

You can use the split function

Comment: That worked for me, assuming that `.Ken:000` may vary (because of the name of user`Ken`) and I think the `replace` and `replaceAll` can't fit for that.